# How to stop asp page downloading

Tags: asp-classic

I heard that it is possible to download asp pages to view the server side script. (asp classic by the way) And I want to make sure this is not possible.  What steps can I take to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible if your server is misconfigured to serve up files with the .asp extension rather than process them server side.

If you see your .asp files are being processed, the text of the script cannot be viewed by a web browser.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure how would I check to make sure that my server was not misconfigured?

Comment: @kricket: Browse to one of your .asp pages.  If you see the source code, your server is misconfigured.